# Android phone fails to connect ethernet cable automatically

Tags: android

I have a Samsung S20 phone (running Android, of course), that's mounted in a drone controller module, such that only its screen is showing. On the outside of the module I have a special ethernet (because it combines ethernet and USB) cable connecting the module to a handheld Wave Relay radio.
With the radio and module connected by the cable, when I power the radio first, then power the phone later (after a minute), the phone displays the ethernet connection, and all works as expected.
With the radio and module connected by the cable, when I power the phone first, then power the radio later (after a minute), the phone does not display the ethernet connection, and the radio and phone never connects by ethernet with each other. Never, that is, until I disconnect and reconnect the ethernet cable between the two. In that case, the phone displays the ethernet connection, and all works as expected.
Is there a setting (or something else) on the phone that will allow this ethernet connection auto-discovery to take place automatically, without resorting to disconnecting and reconnecting the ethernet cable?
Thanks!